# Ubuntu 20.04 new fresh LVM on 5TiB shows just 4.1 TiB space

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, disk-space-utilization, fdisk

On a fresh installed Ubuntu 20.04 I attached second disk with size of 5 TiB. I used following commands to create LVM.

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 5 TiB, 5497558138880 bytes, 10737418240 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

`sudo pvcreate /dev/sdb`

`sudo vgcreate vg_tor /dev/sdb`

`sudo lvcreate -l 100%FREE -n lvm_tor vg_tor`

`mkfs.ext4 /dev/vg_tor/lvm_tor`

`fdisk -l` shows

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 5 TiB, 5497558138880 bytes, 10737418240 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/vg_tor-lvm_tor: 4.102 TiB, 5497553944576 bytes, 10737410048 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

What could be the case of the missing 900GiB?

Comment: Maybe too much disk allocation on install

Answer (score 1):

What is the size of the sdb partition for your lvm?

You can find it by running:

```
 fdisk /dev/sdb
```

Then you can follow this:

```
Command (m for help): d
Partition number (1,2, default 2):
Partition 2 is deleted

Command (m for help): n
Partition type:
   p   primary (1 primary, 0 extended, 3 free)
   e   extended
Select (default p):
Using default response p
Partition number (2-4, default 2):
First sector ('YOUR FIRST SECTOR'-'TO END', default 'YOUR DEFAULT VALUE'):
Using default value 'YOUR DEFAULT VALUE'
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G} ('YOUR FIRST SECTOR'-'TO END', default 'YOUR DEFAULT VALUE'):
Using default value 'YOUR DEFAULT VALUE'
Partition 2 of type Linux and of size 'THIS IS YOUR SIZE' is set

Command (m for help): t
Partition number (1,2, default 2): 8e
Partition number (1,2, default 2):
Hex code (type L to list all codes): 8e
Changed type of partition 'Linux' to 'Linux LVM'

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sdb: 'YOUR DISK SIZE', 'YOUR DISK bytes', 'YOUR DISK sectors'
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 'YOUR DISK IDENTIFIER'

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        ...         ...       ...      83  Linux
/dev/sdb2            ...         ...       ...      8e  Linux LVM

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered!

Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.

WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 16: Device or resource busy.
The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at
the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)
Syncing disks.
```

And looking for 'THIS IS YOUR SIZE' to see your max LVM partition size.

Now we need resize the physical volume.

```
pvresize /dev/sdb2
```

Take a look at the size of the logical volume using the

```
lvdisplay
```

Now extend your logical volume with:

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE /Path/To/Your/LV
```

-l is for disk extents

+100%FREE to add all free extents

Then verify this using the

```
  lvdisplay
```

Then resize ext4 file systems

```
resize2fs /dev/'Your VG'/'Your LV'
```